# What functions work with JuMPArrays?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Is there a way to make certain functions such as `isinteger()` work with JuMPArrays?
I am using Julia/JuMP to solve an optimization problem, and after I get the solution, I want to check if the solution is integer. So here is what I wrote:

```
@defVar(m, 0<= x[1:3] <= 1)
...
xstar = getValue(x)
if isinteger(xstar)
  ...
end
```

And I get an error saying isinteger() has no method matching isinteger(::JuMPArray).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in general you can get an underlying array from a `JuMPArray` by using `[:]`, e.g.

```
m = Model()
@variable(m, 0 <= x[1:3] <= 1)
@variable(m, 0 <= y[1:10, 1:10] <= 1)
solve(m)
xstar = getvalue(x)[:]
ystar = getvalue(y)[:,:]
```

Note that the reason for this is that JuMPArrays don't have to start with index 1, so the user needs to explicitly say they want a normal Julia array before doing things.

Regardless, you shouldn't use `isinteger`. Solvers don't always return very precise answers, e.g. they might say `x[1] = 0.999996` but they really mean it is `1`. You should do something like

```
for i in 1:3
    if getvalue(x[i]) >= 0.999
        println("x[$i] is 1!")
    elseif getvalue(x[i]) <= 0.001
        println("x[$i] is 0!")
    end
end
```

to make sure you don't get any false negatives. If the variable is restricted to be integer or binary, use `iround`, e.g.

```
for i in 1:3
    v = iround(getvalue(x[i]))
    if v == 1
        println("x[$i] is 1!")
    elseif v == 0
        println("x[$i] is 0!")
    end
end
```

but it looks like in this case you are just seeing if the solution is naturally 0 or 1.

Comment: Actually we recommend using ``iround(x[i])``.

Comment: IainDunning adding `[:]` didn't help! I still couldn't use `isinteger` with `xstar`. Also, could you please refer me to a document describing the difference between JuMPArrays and Julia ones. 
And about the `isinteger` function, isn't good to have a precision threshold so that it can recognize `0.9999` as `1`? Something like `isinteger(value,precision)`.

Comment: @mlubin the `iround` thing will only work if its actually `Bin`, in the example its just a continuous variable.

Comment: @Ana `isinteger` maybe should have a precision argument - you could file an issue on the Julia GitHub page suggesting that. There isn't a document describing the differences yet that I know of, we should make one. I've rewritten my answer to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: I am trying to run the [sudoku example](http://www.juliaopt.org/notebooks/JuMP-Sudoku.html) on JuliaBox (julia 0.5) but on `if iround(x_val[i,j,k]) == 1` I got the error `UndefVarError: iround not defined` (removing iround() then works, at least with GLPK)